# How can I clear the "Auto Backup" data to get a clean install?

Tags: backup, uninstallation, google-backup

When I delete and then later re-add an app, the app doesn't start "clean".  Instead it "remembers" things from the last time the app was installed, which I do not want.

I have tried `settings > (specific app) > storage > clear data`  and `settings > (specific app) > storage > clear cache`, but despite those actions, there are things the app remembers.  And even if I delete the app at that point, then reinstall it, it remembers things, so this is not a clean install.

How can I delete the app data or clear the app data or remove the app data that is saved (and later restored) by the Android Auto Backup process?